# Identity Server 4 - unauthorized client

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am struggling with basic setup of the Identity Server 4 with Net Core 3.0 and React (but this is almost irrelevant).

I have generated new app by `dotnet new react -au Individual`, updated dependencies etc, Created config basically copied from the demo server with the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                // JavaScript Client
                new Client
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    ClientId = "spa",
                    ClientName = "SPA (Code + PKCE)",

                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequireConsent = false,

                    RedirectUris = { "https://notused" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://notused" },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "email", "api" },

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse
                },
            };
        }
```

In my startup:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer(o =>
                {
                    o.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = "/myErrorsHandler";
                    o.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    o.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    o.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    o.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                })
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
.AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())   ;
```

Then I am trying in Postman: [image]
and always getting:

```
{"displayMode":null,"uiLocales":null,"error":"unauthorized_client","errorDescription":"Unknown client or client not enabled","requestId":"0HLPL86NBMDRG:00000001","redirectUri":null,"responseMode":null,"clientId":"spa"}
```

I really don't understand why this is not working.
The same client on demo server with the same in Postman dialog works without any issues.

UPDATE:
I found this docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#application-profiles
but I am still not able to get it working.
It recognizes the client, but despite the config (SPA, IdentityServerSPA) throwing:

```
{"displayMode":null,"uiLocales":null,"error":"invalid_request","errorDescription":"code challenge required","requestId":"0HLPL8VD22382:00000001","redirectUri":"http://localhost:5000/authentication/login-callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=code%20challenge%20required#_=_","responseMode":"query","clientId":"spa"}
```

UPDATE 2:
It is "working" with client defined in configuration JSON but only with predefined templates as per doc, but it is impossible (or possibility is not documented) to disable PKCE to make it work e.g. with Postman etc.

Comment: How to do it in appsettigs.json

Comment: *Unknown client or client not enabled* means you provided a wrong client_id with your request. and *code challenge required* means that postman does not support PKCE [I don't use Postman, but google gives me that](https://community.getpostman.com/t/pkce-with-postman/6515)

Comment: Any help to change it to disable PKCE within appsettings.json `  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    },
    "Clients": {
      "spa": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: not sure how to handle that with profiles, they are more or less hardcoded, but you can start whit [this](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/6_javascript_client.html) configuration where set `RequirePkce = false`

Comment: It does not work at all with clients defined in code :/ just does not load it for some reason

Comment: it is executed but the client not being used

Comment: spa will work without issue when defined in json with the predefined base , but any id won't work with the code...

Comment: I've tried.client is recognized but no way to disable pkce

Comment: well, [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/7bf660947baf8966cd65ae6a3708cf283576dc25/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/Options/ClientBuilder.cs) is the place where the profiles come from. Up to me, if [pre-defined](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer/src/IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.cs#L52) solution doesn't work for you, you can remove `AddApiAuthorization()`, or at least move it up in your service builder calls, so that it will not override your manual config

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199230/discussion-between-m-u-and-d-f).

Answer (score 4):

You're not defining the `client_secret`. Based on the code you've provided on the client's configuration you did not setup a client secret, so If no client secret is specified, there's no direct way for your client to prove its authenticity to your Authority (IDserver). This is when PKCE comes in handy, at least you can guarantee that same system is doing both requests.

I see you're asking to disable PKCE, that should not be possible (I'm not sure if it can be done but you definitely shouldn't do that) because you're using code authentication grant for an SPA. (which is the current recommended way of doing things)

As an SPA is a non-confidential client (uncapable of keeping a secret secure) this means that any other application could use your client_id `spa` to make requests to the token endpoint. To prevent this we combine two things:

- Redirect URI: this enforces the response code token to be redirected to a previously known address which should be your client (unless using hosts file to suplant your site)
- PKCE: a mechanism that aims to guarantee that both `/authorize` and `/token` requests come from the same client, so even if someone manages to intercept the code, he/she should not be able to use it in exchange for a token, because not knowing the original secret used in PKCE.

Comment: I don't think it's correct. you can use client without the secret.

Comment: @MU, the concern about the secret is correct from the security perspective. PKCE is a real alternative to the secret, however in IdSrv the settings are independent and the secret requirement can be disabled for test purposes

Comment: @MU what should be there anyway is `RedirectUris = { "https://notused" }`, and that must match the Url you set as `Callback URL` in the Postman, or the real callback route in your web app

Comment: I have tried something like this:
`            services.AddIdentityServer(o => { o.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = "/myErrorsHandler"; })
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(c =>
                {
                    c.Clients = new ClientCollection(GetClients());
                });`
with the client configured as in the post but it is not loading the client. It is creating some client called as my project (however still not available later on)

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the `unauthorized_client` error for the *Resource Owner Password Validation* flow in IdentityServer 4 because the grant type `password` was missing in `[dbo].[ClientGrantTypes]` for the associated `client_id`.
I had to insert a new line into the table to fix this error.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ClientGrantTypes] (
     [GrantType]
    ,[ClientId])
VALUES ('password', X) --where X is value of [dbo].[Clients].[Id] of used client
```